# Redirect from external page after ajax submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hello i'm using an ajax script redirecting to a php page where i make the validation. After there are no validation errors i want to redirect to another page but i cant manage to make it work. here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function() { 


            $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                        target:  \'#preview \',

        });

            });

</script>
```

and here is the external php were i make the validation

```
<?php
require_once('../core/dbconfig.php');
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$fname=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$type=$_POST['type'];
$story=$_POST['story'];
$cookie=$_COOKIE['cookie'];
$sizee = $_FILES['img1']['size'];
if (!$fname or !$city or !$email or !$country or (!$story && $sizee==0))
{

if ($sizee==0 && !$story)
{
echo'<p style="color:red;">Please upload a photo or type your story.<p>';
}

if(!$fname)
{
echo'<p style="color:red;">Please enter your name.<p>';
}
$regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/'; 
if (preg_match($regex, $email)) {
}
else
{
echo'<p style="color:red">Please enter a valid email.<p>';
}
if(!$country)
{
echo'<p style="color:red">Please select your country.<p>';
}
if(!$city)
{
echo'<p style="color:red">Please enter your city.<p>';
}
}
else
{
....
}
```

what i want to achiev is that after all the conditions are completed to redirect to a confirmation page. If i use a succes:window.location.href = "example.php" doesnt work as intended.
Thnx in advance.

Comment: use header location after validate errors

Comment: where is your redirect code after complition

Comment: it should be in that else, i tryed with window.location.href, header() but since it's ajax submit it doesnt redirect

Comment: you can echo 'success' in php file and in ajax response you can check if(data=='success') window.location.href='confirmation.php'

Comment: like this? `<script type="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function() { 
  
          
   $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
      target:  \'#preview \',
      success:
      if(data==\'success\') 
    {
    window.location.href=\'confirmation.php\';
    }
   
  });
   
   });

</script>`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(myform).ajaxForm({

      beforeSend: function() { 

      },
      error: function() {

      }, 
      complete: function(response) { 
           window.location.href='yourfile.php'
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With ajaxForm you'r can use function **complete**, according to documentation this function... "A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed)".

But you need consider property **async**, By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false.

```
$(myform).ajaxForm({
    async: true,
    error: function(response) {
        //something is wrong
    },    
    complete: function(response) { 
        window.location.href='yourfile.php'
    }
});
```

OR

```
$(myform).ajaxForm({
    async: false,
    error: function(response) {
        //something is wrong
    },
    complete: function(response) { 
        window.location.href='yourfile.php'
    }
});
```

Comment: i tryed this it redirects but it passes the verification from the php file, it redirects even if conditions are not true

Comment: of course it is just happens to run an ajax function after your procedure, you must validate your php file that all values ​​be present and return an **error** so that it catches ajaxForm

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "friends/get_user_friends",
        data:{
            action:"action",
            type:"type"
        },
        success: function (response) {               
           window.location.href = "http://google.com";                
        },
        error: function (response, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

        }            
    });
```